# How to merge the contents of a folder under a different branch to a new folder in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I had created a new branch under svn a while back and now need to merge that into the trunk. The issue is that I also need to move it under a different folder than it was in before and I am unclear on how to achieve this from other posts.

This is the directory structure

```
|--branches
|   |--V6_2_1_Branch
|      |--licensing
|         |--SLG
|            |--WebContent
|               |--License Generator
|                  { Contents I want to move }
|
|--trunk
   |--licensing
       |--LG2 (New Folder since the other branch was created)
          |-- licenseWebPortal (Where I want to put the contents)
```

I generally use tortoise cvs, but we just moved to svn. (I know we are behind the times but it is legacy product)

Comment: Good to see you got it figured out - an alternative would have been to merge it in the old location back into trunk and then move the files in two distinct steps. It's also worth noting that on most teams it is a branch creator/user's responsibility to ensure that the branch is kept up to date with trunk, regularly merging down to the branch any changes which have been made. It can reduce the number of conflicts when you finally go to reintegrate the branch into trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using the "Merging Two Different Trees" method. Just made sure to list the trunk in the from field. From the docs, "In the From: field enter the full folder URL of the trunk. This may sound wrong, but remember that the trunk is the start point to which you want to add the branch changes."